# Is there an issue with the number of views?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if it is because it takes time (the cache thing) or if it is really an issue, but has anyone else noticed that the number of views is not giving an accurate measure of the number of times that a question has been viewed  (or the number of people who viewed a question)?

An example is a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130/clojure-versus-r-advantages-and-disadvantages-for-data-analysis) I asked. It says that it has been viewed 3 times, but at least 4 people commented/answered the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views change rapidly compared to votes- so the server may be caching a snapshot of the number of views and then using that number for a while before updating.

It is a common trick used by websites to handle high load.

Answer (score 3):

This is buffered, as Sharpie mentioned, and also we calculate views very conservatively.

It's mostly only an issue when traffic is very low during the start of the private beta.